# Creating A floating popup list

Tags: android, list, popup

I want to create a popup window like the link given bellow. I thought it would be using QuickContactBabage but it is not. and just not geyting how to create it.

[image link http://cdn3.staztic.com/screenshots/android-swim-32-2.jpg](http://cdn3.staztic.com/screenshots/android-swim-32-2.jpg)

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Hope this helps you](https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction3D)

Comment: What have you from clicking on first link. And, [Try this one](https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction3D/zipball/master)

Comment: [Try this](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/69670844/lorensiuswlt-NewQuickAction3D-v1.0.1-0-g4273b56.zip) also [this](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By extending [PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html) you can do whatever you need like your requirement. Below is the main code for, popwindow shown process.

```
ActionItem nextItem     = new ActionItem(ID_DOWN, "Next", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.menu_down_arrow));
ActionItem prevItem     = new ActionItem(ID_UP, "Prev", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.menu_up_arrow));
ActionItem searchItem   = new ActionItem(ID_SEARCH, "Find", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.menu_search));
ActionItem infoItem     = new ActionItem(ID_INFO, "Info", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.menu_info));
ActionItem eraseItem    = new ActionItem(ID_ERASE, "Clear", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.menu_eraser));
ActionItem okItem       = new ActionItem(ID_OK, "OK", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.menu_ok));

//use setSticky(true) to disable QuickAction dialog being dismissed after an item is clicked
prevItem.setSticky(true);
nextItem.setSticky(true);

//create QuickAction. Use QuickAction.VERTICAL or QuickAction.HORIZONTAL param to define layout 
//orientation
final QuickAction quickAction = new QuickAction(this, QuickAction.VERTICAL);

//add action items into QuickAction
quickAction.addActionItem(nextItem);
quickAction.addActionItem(prevItem);
quickAction.addActionItem(searchItem);
quickAction.addActionItem(infoItem);
quickAction.addActionItem(eraseItem);
quickAction.addActionItem(okItem);
```

By, trying [NewQuickAction3D](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/69670844/lorensiuswlt-NewQuickAction3D-v1.0.1-0-g4273b56.zip) exmample, you'll get an output like below -

[image]

Also, have a look at here [QuickAction Dialog in Android](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/)

Comment: I dont know why I am not able to find class called ActionItem

Comment: @Parth Did you download that example?